# good idea to use cache for username and password rest api authentication?

Tags: hibernate, api, rest, ehcache

I wanted to somehow reduce latency by using hibernates second level cache to cache user objects so that each api request call (with a username and password) would not have to hit the database.

Basically I'm expected a huge number of api calls per day, and i dont want to hit my mysql store for username and password lookup in addition to the mongo db store to retrieve the actual data. So I thought using ehcache or something may help prevent this?

Are there any other strategies to address the above? This will be mainly machine to machine api calls not really browser based.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice with caching is that **you cache the information that rarely changes. Like `Country, States` etc. and it is not preferred to cache the transactional data.**

There are no specific answer to your question but I would not prefer to cache the user login information as I consider it as transactional data.

Read more information about hibernate cache [here](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/03/24/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-three-the-second-level-cache/) or read the [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache).

Comment: Sure you are right, but how would one prevent a username password lookup per rest api call? Due to the stateless nature I cant think of another way to optimise this @ManuPK